# Is Jenkins supposed to clear a jobs upstream dependencies if they are removed from the Maven POM?

Tags: maven, jenkins

Dependencies in our jobs have a tendency to change a lot as we are working on something new and we sort of have to discover the best way to put it together.

But it seems that even though we try to reduce dependencies between our modules as much as possible. Jenkins isn't quite as willing to let go. And will keep removed dependencies in the list of upstream jobs.

It seems we can't manually change the list anywhere. So does anyone know if this is expected behaviour or just some setting we haven't found? Or a bug?

Comment: Have you tried reloading the job or the full jenkins configuration?

Comment: We restart it fairly often to test out various plugins (or just updates). But I just tried a reload for a project I know has changed since last restart. And that didn't change anything

Comment: Seems that some of the dependencies I had was from old job modules that was no longer used. Deleting them clears up at least some of the upstream dependencies